# How can a graphics card support a max resolution of 2560x1600 but be able to support two monitors at this resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-geforce

I have an [NVidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_8_series) card that supports 2560x1600 max resolution. It can support driving two displays via the dual dual link DVI connectors. Pardon my ignorance but how can it have a max resolution which is lower than the combined resolution of the two displays?  If my math hasn't completely failed me 2560x1600 = 4M pixels. So how can it drive two monitors at this resolution, effectively pushing 8M pixels, when it can only drive one monitor at 4M pixels?  Am I thinking of this incorrectly? Is it a limitation of the architecture of the onboard chips? If I only hook up one monitor am I effectively only using half the card? To me it's like saying a car can carry two people at 80mph, but only one at 40mph. I'm curious as to what the limiting factor is here.

Comment: Depends on the card, if it is a "Dual head" card and supports that resolution on both heads, then yes. Read the specs for the card. Post your specific model please.

Comment: This is what it is.  http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_8800_gt_us.html To be fully clear it is the mac version.

Comment: Wow. The GeForce 8800. That takes me back (in this case, to 2006). :)

Comment: I think it is becoming clear that I misinterpreted the specs. I thought it could run two displays at 2560x1600 when in fact that appears to be the max resolution of all attached displays.  That is what I was really getting at.

Answer (score 1):

> To me it's like saying a car can carry two people at 80mph, 
>   but only one at 40mph. I'm curious as to what the limiting factor is here.

You might be very close to explaining it here.

I can have a taxi service with two cars, each having a max speed of 40kmph.
That does not mean that when it uses a single car that that car can suddenly drive 80kmph.

Now take your card which apparently has two dual link DVI connectors. A dual link DVI connector supports a resolution of 2560 x 1600. No more. That is simply its max bandwidth.

With two such connectors you could connect up to two monitors, each at 2560x1600 max.
It still would not be able to drive a single display at a higher resolution as lonmg as it uses dual-link DVI (dual link DVI here means one regular DVI cable, with two data connections. There also exists single link DVI which only supports up to 1920x1200).

If you want higher resolutions, then move to display port.

Comment: So the max resolution is truly the number of pixels the card can push. So this card would be unable to push two WQHD (2560x1080) at full resolution.  In would be able to do it on one, but not two.  To push two WQHD displays, I'd need a different gfx card or an additional gfx card, correct?

Comment: You need a card which is capable of handling enough pixels **and** a way to get those pixels to the displays. In the case of DVI connection the limiting factor is getting that pixel data to the display. DVI is from the last millenium, it simply was not designed for todays resolutions.